# set null and cascade at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have a table referenced by two other tables with foreign keys.

What delete rule should I use in order to set the foreign key in one table to null, and delete the corresponding row in the other table?

For example you want to delete a department , and when doing so you want to delete all the department's projects which are in another table, but set the `deptnumber` attribute of the employees of that department to null instead of deleting them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have two referencing tables. Thus, two FK-s. So define first as `ON DELETE CASCADE` and second as `ON DELETE SET NULL`

Comment: [*Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). `ON DELETE SET NULL` is valid and can be used.

Comment: You've practically given the answer yourself. Unclear to me where/why you are stuck.

Comment: Oops , I was under the impression that the `ON DELETE` statement should be stated in the parent table. Sorry for the bother  , and thanks to all  of you